# ターミナルにて subl test と打ち込んでも Sublime Text が開かない

Tags: sublimetext

## 解決したい問題

subl testとターミナルで打ち込んでSublime Textを開きたいのですがPATHがうまく通らないので開くことができません。
考えられる原因や調べた方がいいことなどを教えていただきたいです。

## 試したこと

sublが開けないのはPATHが通ってないからということで[このHP](https://datawokagaku.com/what_is_path/)を参考にPATHが通るように紹介されているコードを実行してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。

## 環境

M1 Mac

## 現状

●Applicationsの下にSublime Text.appはあります

```py
nakamotokenta@nakamotokentanoMacBook-Air Sublime Text.app % pwd
/Applications/Sublime Text.app
```

●binの中にもsublはあります

```py
nakamotokenta@nakamotokentanoMacBook-Air Sublime Text.app % cd Contents/SharedSupport/bin
nakamotokenta@nakamotokentanoMacBook-Air bin % ls
subl
```

●僕のPATHはこれです

```py
/Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/bin:/Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

●/usr/local/binというフォルダはありました

```py
nakamotokenta@nakamotokentanoMacBook-Air bin % cd /usr/local/bin
nakamotokenta@nakamotokentanoMacBook-Air bin % pwd
/usr/local/bin
```

●/Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/binというフォルダはありませんでした(自分的にはこれが原因なのかと思っています)

```py
nakamotokenta@nakamotokentanoMacBook-Air bin % cd /Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/bin
cd: no such file or directory: /Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/bin
```

## 実行結果がこれです

## 1

```py
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/bin.
```

講座に載っていたコードの『/usr/local/bin』を変更し、これを実行したら

```py
ln: /Users/nakamotokenta/.pyenv/bin.: File exists
```

ファイルは存在すると出てきました

```py
zsh: command not found: subl
```

subl testと打ち込むとこのように表示されました

## 2

```py
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/.
```

講座に載っていたコードをそのまま打ち込むと

```py
ln: /usr/local/bin/./subl: Permission denied
```

アクセス拒否と出てきてしまいました

```py
zsh: command not found: subl
```

subl testと打ち込むとこのように表示されました

Comment: 2 については "Permission denied" と表示されていますので、`sudo` コマンドを使うなどして root 権限で実行する必要があります。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！知識不足のため`sudo`コマンドとroot権限の意味がわからないため調べてみます！

Answer (score 1):

```
＄sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

を実行し、フォルダ内の所有者を自分自身に変更することで解決できました。
cubickさんhataさん返信ありがとうございました。

[このサイトの追記事項を見落としていました](https://datawokagaku.com/what_is_path/)

Answer (score 0):

以下のように実行してシンボリックリンクを作成した後、改めて `subl` と実行してみてください。

```
$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうござます！　　上記コードを実行してみたのですが  `ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: Permission denied`  と表示され、その後、sublと打ち込んでも`zsh: command not found: subl`  表示されました