# Mac で subl コマンドを実行しても Sublime Text が起動しない

Tags: macos, sublimetext

#### 問題点

`subl` コマンドをターミナルに入力してもsublime textが起動しない

#### 環境

MacBook Pro

#### 試したこと

下記サイトを手順通りに実施

[Macで「PATHを通す」をちゃんと理解する](https://datawokagaku.com/what_is_path/)
[ターミナルにて subl test と打ち込んでも Sublime Text が開かない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82918)

```
yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/. 
ln: /usr/local/bin/./subl: File exists
yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin                                                 
Password:
yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % subl test                                                                              
zsh: command not found: subl
yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ %
```

#### 検証項目

`ls /usr/local/bin` の実行結果

```
Sublime             docker-credential-desktop   kubectl.docker
com.docker.cli          docker-credential-ecr-login subl
docker              docker-credential-osxkeychain   vpnkit
docker-compose          hub-tool
docker-compose-v1       kubectl
```

##### 「回答1」の検証結果

```
yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % ls /usr/local/bin/subl
/usr/local/bin/subl
yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`
bquote>
```

##### 「回答1」の検証結果その2

```
(base) yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % ls /usr/local/bin/subl
/usr/local/bin/subl
(base) yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
(base) yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % subl test             
zsh: command not found: subl
```

Comment: ターミナルで、`echo $PATH`と入力してみて、`:`で区切られたリストに`/usr/local/bin`が含まれているか確認して見て下さい。

Comment: yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
と表示されています。

Comment: では`/usr/local/bin/subl`と入力すると何が起きますか？

Comment: yuta@yuutanoMacBook-Pro ~ % /usr/local/bin/subl
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/subl
、、、そんなファイルは存在しない、という意味でしょうか

Comment: そうですね。`ls /usr/local/bin`で`subl`コマンドのリンクファイルがあるか確認して見て下さい

Comment: Sublime    docker-credential-desktop kubectl.docker
com.docker.cli   docker-credential-ecr-login subl
docker    docker-credential-osxkeychain vpnkit
docker-compose   hub-tool
docker-compose-v1  kubectl

Comment: 見づらくてすみません。どうやってコード形式で貼るのかもわからず、、

Comment: 質問本文に、インデント4空白で`ls /usr/local/bin`の結果を貼り付けて下さい

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問本文に追記しました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls /usr/local/bin/subl
```

と打ち込んで、

```
/usr/local/bin/subl
```

と出ない場合は、もう一度

```
rm /usr/local/bin/subl
```

としてから

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

とリンクを張り直して下さい

Comment: 結果を質問本文へ追記しました

Comment: /usr/local/bin/subl`の最後のバッククオートが余計でした。すみません。

Comment: 改めて実行しました。とくに何も変化はありません

Comment: 我が家のMacBook Proの環境ではこれでsublime textが起動しているんですが

Comment: 質問本文に現状を追記しました。まだnot foundのままのようです、、

Comment: ターミナルで`rehash`としてから、`subl test`とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: rehashしても変化なしです、、not foundのままですね

Comment: 結果を良く見直したのですが、`rm /usr/local/bin/subl`は実行しましたか？

Comment: できるようになりました！ありがとうございます。大変失礼しました。。もしよければ何が原因で何を行ったのかご教示いただくことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 状況から考えるに、`/usr/local/bin/subl`コマンドがあって、リンクが間違っていたのだと思います。なので、一度間違ったリンクの`subl`コマンドを削除して改めて（シンボリック）リンクを張り直したら上手くいったということでしょう。

Comment: なるほどです、、そういえば最初にシンボリックを叩いたとき、「Sublime\ Text.app」のエスケープ文字を消してから入力していました。それが原因でずっと間違ったPATHのリンクを読み込んでいた、、、という理解でしょうか。いずれにしてもありがとうございます！！

Comment: でしたら、`rm /usr/local/bin/Sublime`もしておくといいかもです。

Comment: 入力してみました

Comment: これで、`/usr/local/bin`に余計な、Sublimeというコマンドが消えたことと思います。お疲れ様でした。

Answer (score 1):

SublimeがApplications配下にないように思います。
ダウンロードしてそのまま使っている場合、Sublimeはダウンロードフォルダ配下に存在しますので、Applications配下に移動させたらうまくいくのではないでしょうか。

存在確認

```
ls -la /Applications
```

Sublimeがなければ普段使っている場所からFinderで移動するかそちらにリンクを貼る。
移動後、さらにエラーが出るようなら以下が参考になるかもしれません。
参照：https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/3233